# using terraform with EMR spark, add new step without destroying cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, terraform

I'm using the terraform documentation(https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html) to build an EMR (spark) cluster. I am looking at deploying spark jobs through steps using terraform.

the spark submit would be something like..

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class mypackage.myobject s3://.../my.jar
```

Has anyone tried this functionality and gotten terraform to not destroy the cluster when you add a new step or change a step? Ideally, the steps effected should be the only thing destroyed and created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple answer is that the API defines some actions as requiring a destroy.. nothing terraform can do about that.

I believe this is a limitation of the cloudwatch APIS.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the lifecycle ignore_changes attribute to include whatever is being changed

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  step {
    action = "TERMINATE_CLUSTER"
    name   = "Setup Hadoop Debugging"

    hadoop_jar_step {
      jar  = "command-runner.jar"
      args = ["state-pusher-script"]
    }
  }

  # Optional: ignore outside changes to running cluster steps
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["step"]
  }
}
```

That code is taken from the example taken from 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#enable-debug-logging